How to prove whether the integrals of two equivalent infinitesimal functions are also equivalent infinitesimal in certain cases
My question is:

If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both continuous functions, and $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1$, which means that f(x) and g(x) are equivalent infinitesimals. So, suppose there are continuous functions a(x) and b(x), which both tend to 0 when x tends to 0, then is the following conclusion:
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x, t) dt}{\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}g(x, t) dt} = 1$$
absolutely correct? Or are they only correct under certain special conditions? How to determine this condition (if any)?

For example:

Becase:$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^{x^2} - 1}{x^2} = 1$$
If we define $a(x) = x$ and $b(x) = -x$, so the following limit:
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}[e^{(x-t)^2} - 1]\sin(t) dt}{\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}(x-t)^2tdt}$$ is also equals to 1?

Much appreciated.
PS:
I am a beginner in both math and Stack Exchange. I asked this question because it seems that this problem cannot be simply proved by L'Hôpital's rule. Maybe for specific functions, some methods can be used to calculate their limits, but I am a little curious whether this conclusion can be proved to be correct and can be used directly (for example, in some equivalent infinitesimal substitutions).

for the first one, it's better using another letter for the variable of integration

Did you already learn the l'Hospital rule?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You succeeded to reopen the post, by focusing as required on a single question. But you should also update the title and remove the first sentence (strangely beginning with "If").

For any continuous function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ (no need of $f(0)=0$), we always have :
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x \to 0} \int_0^x f(t)dt =0
\end{equation*}
To see this, just consider $f(t)dt$ the whole thing as a measure. By fundamental theorem of calculus and L'Hôpital's rule, we have :
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\int_0^x f(t)dt}{\int_0^x g(t)dt} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1
\end{equation*}
For the case of two variables, suppose that $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, $a : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $b: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. If we assume just like the first part that $f$ is continuous, $a(x) \to 0$ and $b(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$. We can still write a few steps. Bound $f$ on $[-1,1]^2$ by $M >0$. Then, when $0 < x < 1$ :
\begin{equation*}
|\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t)dt| \leqslant M |b(x)-a(x)|
\end{equation*}
If $a(x) \to 0$ and $b(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$, then the integral tends to zero. By Leibniz rule :
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t)dt}{\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t)dt} = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x,b(x))b'(x) - f(x,a(x))a'(x) + \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(x,t)dt}{g(x,b(x))b'(x) - g(x,a(x))a'(x) + \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}g(x,t)dt}
\end{equation*}
One will have to evaluate the limit. There is no general conclusion.

You are right. I was stupid.

"There is no general conclusion" with your attempt (provided tacit additional regularity hypothesis) to use L'Hospital, but this doesn't prove that another method could be conclusive.
